# Bash mapping two arrays

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I have 2 arrays defined below.

**Arr1**

```
"name": "key1", "value": "value1"
"name": "key2", "value": "value2"
"name": "key3", "value": "value3"
```

**Arr2**

```
value1=/other/path/to/file1
value3=/other/path/to/file3
```

I want to map these 2 arrays in such a way that my resulting array must look like below.

**Output Array**

```
"name": "key1", "value": "/other/path/to/file1"
"name": "key2", "value": "value2"
"name": "key3", "value": "/other/path/to/file3"
```

So basically I need to write some command in my bash script which will do such mapping and provide me required output.

Output of `declare -p Arr1 Arr2` is:

declare -p arr1 arr2

```
declare -a arr1='([0]="name:" [1]="key1," [2]="value:" [3]="value1" [4]="name:" [5]="key2," [6]="value:" [7]="value2" [8]="name:" [9]="key3," [10]="value:" [11]="value3")'
declare -a arr2='([0]="value1=/other/path/to/file1" [1]="value3=/other/path/to/file3")'
```

Comment: Show us the code form of the `bash` arrays you've maintained

Comment: You say that you have arrays but really, these are just strings, as far as bash is concerned. Can we assume that they're in two separate files? Are the keys and values guaranteed not to contain quotes and colons?

Comment: @TomFenech quotes and columns are all present as given in the example here. I have corrected the arrays. Each line of the above arrays represent a single element of that array.

Comment: We still don't know if these are lines in a script (Arr2 looks like variable assignments in a shell script now), or lines in a text file, or what.

Comment: @TomFenech As I clearly said in my previous comment, each line denote an element of the array. So Arr2[0] is 'value1=/other/path/to/file1' and similarly Arr2[1] is 'value3=/other/path/to/file3'. Hope this clears your confusion now.

Comment: @Shashank: Can you output of `declare -p Arr1 Arr2`

Comment: Value of 'declare -p Arr1 Arr2' is : 
`declare -a arr1='([0]="name:" [1]="key1," [2]="value:" [3]="value1" [4]="name:" [5]="key2," [6]="value:" [7]="value2" [8]="name:" [9]="key3," [10]="value:" [11]="value3")'
declare -a arr2='([0]="value1=/other/path/to/file1" [1]="value3=/other/path/to/file3")'`

Comment: Please [edit] that into the question.

Comment: @TomFenech added.

Comment: Note that what you previously said, "Each line of the above arrays represent a single element of that array", is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Script.sh

```
array1=( '"name": "key1", "value": "value1"'
'"name": "key2", "value": "value2"'
'"name": "key3", "value": "value3"' )

array2=( 'value1=/other/path/to/file1' 'value3=/other/path/to/file3' )

for element in "${array2[@]}"
do
    key=`echo $element | cut -d '=' -f1`
    value=`echo $element | cut -d '=' -f2-`
    i=0
    for elem in "${array1[@]}"
    do
        array1[i]=`echo $elem | sed -e "s#$key#$value#"`
        (( i++ ))
    done
done

for element in "${array1[@]}"
do
   echo $element
done
```

## Result:

```
./test.sh 
"name": "key1", "value": "/other/path/to/file1"
"name": "key2", "value": "value2"
"name": "key3", "value": "/other/path/to/file3"
```

Comment: This would only give what is present in second array mapping with first array. I hav edited the output array to give me exact result. Please have a look at updated value and see if you could help.

Comment: Added the output that I got. Can you please mention the change in this output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script in `bash`:

```
declare -a arr1='([0]="name:" [1]="key1," [2]="value:" [3]="value1" [4]="name:" [5]="key2," [6]="value:" [7]="value2" [8]="name:" [9]="key3," [10]="value:" [11]="value3")'
declare -a arr2='([0]="value1=/other/path/to/file1" [1]="value3=/other/path/to/file3")'

arr=()

for i in "${arr1[@]}"; do
   s="$i"
   if [[ $i =~ ^value[0-9]+$ ]]; then
      for j in "${arr2[@]}"; do
         if [[ $j == $i"="* ]]; then
            s="${j#$i=}"
            break
         fi
      done
   fi
   arr+=("$s")
done

# print formatted output
#declare -p arr
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
   printf "%s" "$i"
   ((++n % 4 == 0)) && printf "\n" || printf " "
done
```

**Output:**

```
name: key1, value: /other/path/to/file1
name: key2, value: value2
name: key3, value: /other/path/to/file3
```